# Need help to increase code coverage for trigger , presently only 42% achieved

Tags: trigger, unit-test

Below is the trigger:

```
trigger t_DisableAttachements on Attachment(before insert,before delete,after update) {
    Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('T-OPP-DCVF-RT').getRecordTypeId();
    Id devRecordTypeId1 = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('DC-VF Read only RT').getRecordTypeId();

     for (Attachment att:Trigger.new){

         String parentObjId = att.ParentId;     //It will get profitability obj id.  
         list<opportunity> pid= [select t_locked__c,recordtypeid from Opportunity where t_locked__c=true ];// it get list of opp locked records.
         list<t_Profitability__c> ids=[Select t_opportunity__c from t_Profitability__c where id=:att.ParentId];
         for(t_Profitability__c pro:ids){
             for(opportunity opp:pid){    
                 if(parentObjId.startsWith('a3r') && opp.t_locked__c==true && opp.id==pro.t_opportunity__c && opp.recordtypeid==devRecordTypeId )//a3r is the starting sting in ID for all Profitability
                 {
                     att.addError('Since this opportunity was submitted for approval, you are not allowed to add a new attachment.');
                 }
                 else if(parentObjId.startsWith('a3r') && opp.t_locked__c==true && opp.id==pro.t_opportunity__c && opp.recordtypeid==devRecordTypeId1)
                 {
                     att.addError('Since this opportunity was closed, you are not allowed to add a new attachment.');
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
@isTest
    public class t_DisableAttachements_Test {
    static testMethod void  t_DisableAttachements(){

    Account acc = new Account(Name='vfvh',montant__c=0.3);
    insert acc;
    acc.name='hjghg';
    update acc;
    Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('T-OPP-DCVF-RT').getRecordTypeId();
    Opportunity opp=new Opportunity();
    RecordType rt = [select Id from RecordType where Name = 'T-OPP-DCVF-RT' and SobjectType = 'opportunity' LIMIT 1];
    opp.RecordTypeId = rt.id; 
    opp.RecordTypeId=devRecordTypeId ;
    opp.t_locked__c = True;
    opp.name='fdf';
    opp.stagename='Draft';
    opp.closedate=System.Today();

    insert opp;
    t_Profitability__c Pro=new t_Profitability__c();
    pro.t_Opportunity__c=opp.Id;
    pro.id='a3rm0000000D6Z5';
            try{
                  insert pro;

               }catch (DMLException e) {}  

    Attachment attach=new Attachment(); 
    attach.Name='TestAtt'; 
    Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body'); 
    attach.body=bodyBlob; 
    attach.parentId=opp.Id; 
    insert attach; 

    List<Attachment> attachments=[select id, name from Attachment where parent.id=:opp.id];
    System.assertEquals(1, attachments.size());
     attach = [SELECT Id, name from Attachment where parent.id=:opp.id];
     delete attach;  

         }
```

}

[image]

Comment: One note, as of spring16, all attachments will ve added as chatter files, not attachment object.  This is a different data model and I don't think your code would protect.  See https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_files_notes_attachments_list.htm

Comment: @Mitesh Did my answer worked for you?

Comment: @Peeyush:  I tried with that way, but no luck. Could you please suggest other way.

Comment: I think you have posted wrong code as in your code there is line  for(t_Profitability__c pro:ids) but in your code coverage image see the red line it has different object Rfleet_profitability__c.

Comment: Because of you are using this line pro.id='a3rm0000000D6Z5'; you didn't mention seeAllData=true so i think your t_Profitability__c  record is not inserting. Because insert is in try block that's why you are not able to see that error. So don't assign this id here.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace this code:**

```
attach.parentId=opp.Id;
```

**With this:**

```
attach.parentId=pro.Id;
```

Use `pro.Id` instead of `opp.Id` in test class.